# Deleting items from ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, onclick, textview, double

I have two buttons Lay1 and Lay2. When the user clicks either some information is put in a Listview(lv) and a textView(inputPrice). When I delete a single item from the ListView it's value from the textView is removed correctly but when two items are in the ListView and I delete a single item the value of the TextView returns to 0. It should still have the value of a the remaining item. How do I keep the value of the remaining item(s) in my TextView?

```
private double overallTotalproduct;
public static TextView resultTextView;
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
setListAdapter(adapter);

ArrayList<String> ai= new ArrayList<String>();
ai = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("list");
if (ai != null) {listItems.add(ai+"");
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}




    final TextView textViewtotalproduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    resultTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);;



final ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
return onLongListItemClick(v,pos,id);}
protected boolean onLongListItemClick(View v, final int pos, long id) {
final String str=lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();  
Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick string=" + str);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new  
AlertDialog.Builder(MenuView2Activity.this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to remove this Item?")
.setCancelable(false)
.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
{listItems.remove(pos);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

TextView textviewlay1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.m1aa);
String stringl1 = textviewlay1.getText().toString();
Double doubl1 = Double.parseDouble(stringl1);       
TextView textviewp1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
String stringp1 = textviewp1.getText().toString();
Double intp1 = Double.parseDouble(stringp1);
resultl1 = intp1 - doubl1;
textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(resultl1));

TextView textviewlay2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.m1ab);
String stringl2 = textviewlay2.getText().toString();
Double doubl2 = Double.parseDouble(stringl2);
TextView textviewp2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
String stringp2 = textviewp2.getText().toString();
Double intp2 = Double.parseDouble(stringp2);
double resultl2 = intp2 - doubl2;
textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(resultl2));}

})
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    dialog.cancel();
    }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    return true;
    }
    });





 lay1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
   TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m1aa);
   String stringm1aa = textView1.getText().toString();
   Double intm1aa = Double.parseDouble(stringm1aa);

   TextView t1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
   String t11 = t1.getText().toString();
   Double int11 = Double.parseDouble(t11);

   listItems.add("1 "+stringm1a+" - "+intm1aa );
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   overallTotalproduct =  intm1aa + int11 ;
   textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(overallTotalproduct));}});

lay2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
   TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m1ab);
   String stringm1ab = textView2.getText().toString();
   Double intm1ab = Double.parseDouble(stringm1ab);

   TextView t2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
   String t12 = t2.getText().toString();
   Double int12 = Double.parseDouble(t12);

   listItems.add("1"+stringm1b+"-"+ intm1ab);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   overallTotalproduct =  intm1ab + int12;
   textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(overallTotalproduct));}});
```

Comment: You should paste your code exactly as how you have it. Is this how you have it?

Comment: You don't have to paste it all, but paste it in the correct order.

Comment: I wish I could offer a bounty for this question

Comment: The solution is to implement multitouch into the ListView and TextView if that's possible or simply delete each item in ListView then setOnLongClickListener to each of the Buttons that sent items to ListView. I'll post the exact answer when I have time. Multitouch between a TextView and ListView is no easy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a lot of help from the SO community from this and my other questions by deleting from the button that sent the items from the List instead of long clicking the List Items themselves. Ignore the many strings and you see this was a far better solution than what I was originally trying to do especially since the user couldn't always see what was present in the ListView anyway after so many insertions into it.

```
lay18.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
 public boolean onLongClick(View v)                                                    {
  LayoutInflater myLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   final View dialogView = myLayout.inflate(R.layout.alerthelp, null);
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
   alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
   final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();



  Button button5 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
   button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {

   TextView ss18=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.s18);//change
   String sss18 = ss18.getText().toString();    //change

   TextView texti18 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);//change
   String stringi18 = texti18.getText().toString();//change
   Double ip18 = Double.parseDouble(stringi18);//change
   if (ip18  > 0){//change
   if (sss18.equals("st")) {//change
   TextView stax18=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.salestax2);//change
   String sax18 = stax18.getText().toString();//change
   double sx18 = Double.parseDouble(sax18);//change
   TextView textviewlay18 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.m4ac);//change
   String stringl18 = textviewlay18.getText().toString();//change
   Double doubl18 = Double.parseDouble(stringl18);//change
   TextView textviewp18 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);//change
   String stringp18 = textviewp18.getText().toString();//change
   Double intp18 = Double.parseDouble(stringp18);//change
   double resultl18 = intp18 - (doubl18*sx18);//change
   int precision21t = 100; //keep 4 digits//change
   resultl18= Math.floor(resultl18 * precision21t +.5)/precision21t;//change
   textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(resultl18));//change
   if 
   (listItems != null)
   try{
  final String str=lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
   Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick string=" + str);
   {listItems.remove(pos);
   TextView text18 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView18);
   dally18=(dally18-1);
   text18.setText(String.valueOf(dally18));
   d18.setText(String.valueOf(dally18));
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   controller1.deletename(stringl18);}
                    }
                    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex )
                    {
                    }

   alertDialog.dismiss();//change
   }else{
   if (sss18.equals("")) {//change
  TextView textviewlay18 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.m4ac);//change
  String stringl18 = textviewlay18.getText().toString();//change
  Double doubl18 = Double.parseDouble(stringl18);//change
  TextView textviewp18 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);//change
  String stringp18 = textviewp18.getText().toString();//change
  Double intp18= Double.parseDouble(stringp18);//change
  double resultl18 = intp18 - doubl18;//change
  int precision21t = 100; //keep 4 digits//change
  resultl18= Math.floor(resultl18 * precision21t +.5)/precision21t;//change
  textViewtotalproduct.setText(String.valueOf(resultl18));//change
   if 
  (listItems != null)
   try{
                    final String str=lv.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                    Log.i("ListView", "onLongListItemClick string=" + str);
                    {listItems.remove(pos);
                    TextView text18 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView18);
                    dally18=(dally18-1);
                    text18.setText(String.valueOf(dally18));
                    d18.setText(String.valueOf(dally18));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    controller1.deletename(stringl18);}
                    }
                    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex )
                    {
                    }
                        alertDialog.dismiss();}}}}});                   



                        alertDialog.show();
                        return true;}});
```